# Search users under organization in Liferay

Tags: java, search, liferay

I have to search users under the specific organization in liferay. At present we have a search available with

`UserLocalService.search()`

which is based on the companyId . I was wondering if there is any otherway even using the DynamicQueryFactoryUtil do fetch along with organization filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dynamic query looks good, but I found an another way. We can pass the organization id using Map.

```
params.put("usersOrgs", orgId); 
List<User> searchResult = liferayUserLocalService.search(companyId, keyword, WorkflowConstants.STATUS_APPROVED, params, 0, -1, "");
```

which will filter the users based on organization.

Comment: I had the same issue. What if I want to filter based on multiple organizations? Can I pass an array of orgIds in the param Map?.
Can you please point me in the direction of documentation for 'usersOrgs'?

Answer (score 0):

Of Course You can use `DynamicQuery` for achieving this.

This can be done in two phase ,

1. Fetch User Id associated with the given Organization.
2. Use search criterion along with the `id` received in first phase.

So, the code will look as following ,

```
    // Fetch userId List form Organization id
    long[] organiztionIds = UserLocalServiceUtil.getOrganizationUserIds(orgId);
    DynamicQuery searchQuery = DynamicQueryFactoryUtil.forClass(User.class, UserLocalServiceUtil.class.getClassLoader());
    Criterion searchCriteria = PropertyFactoryUtil.forName("companyId").eq(companyid);
    //Add Organization Id in Criterion
    if (organiztionIds.length != 0) {
        searchCriteria =
                RestrictionsFactoryUtil.and(RestrictionsFactoryUtil.in("userId", ArrayUtils.toObject(organiztionIds)), searchCriteria);
    }
    if (!firstName.isEmpty()) {
        searchCriteria = RestrictionsFactoryUtil.or(RestrictionsFactoryUtil.eq("firstName", firstName), searchCriteria);
    }
    if (!middleName.isEmpty()) {
        searchCriteria = RestrictionsFactoryUtil.or(RestrictionsFactoryUtil.eq("middleName", middleName), searchCriteria);
    }
    if (!lastName.isEmpty()) {
        searchCriteria = RestrictionsFactoryUtil.or(RestrictionsFactoryUtil.eq("lastName", lastName), searchCriteria);
    }
    if (!screenName.isEmpty()) {
        searchCriteria = RestrictionsFactoryUtil.or(RestrictionsFactoryUtil.eq("screenName", screenName), searchCriteria);
    }
    searchQuery.add(searchCriteria);
    UserLocalServiceUtil.dynamicQuery(searchQuery);
```

P.S

I haven't tested this code. But this is the way to do it.

I Hope it helps you.

Comment: thanks for the response. The dynamic query looks good but I found an another way . `params.put("usersOrgs", orgId);   List<User> searchResult = liferayUserLocalService.search(companyId, keyword, WorkflowConstants.STATUS_APPROVED, params, 0, -1, obc);`